# (Is there any) VB .NET component which bind every event happened on a table in SQL SERVER

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net

Is there any VB .NET component which bind every event happened on a table in SQL SERVER?
I want to build a tiny apps (VB .NET) which always ready.. Then when an event happened on a table (e.g. tbl_tasks) in SQL SERVER, my app will recognize it.

e.g. A new record is INSERTed on tbl_tasks. My app will recognize that something happened with tbl_tasks, then I could do some code on vb.

Is it possible with any .NET components? If not? Is there any sollution which I could try and give me the same result?

Big Thanks!

Comment: There isn't with VB.NET but you may write "triggers" for the same.

Comment: You can watch for queries: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345134%28SQL.90%29.aspx#sqltrc_topic2

Comment: @AVD yeah I could simply use trigger on SQL SERVER but the requirement is it has to be traced by the app.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Thanks for the link. It may solve my problem.

Comment: you maybe able use triggers with a CLR sproc, or simply using a trigger to set a value in a table and poll the table for when this value changes. Perhaps the other avenue to explore is SQL Management Objects (a.k.a SMO)

Answer (score 0):

This is not that easy to do, but I have an idea.  It's possible to monitor a table in SQL Server to determine that last timestamp of when an insert/update/delete was performed on it.  If you have a VB.NET background process running, you could ping this table every 10 seconds to get the last updated date, and if it's different from last time, then you know that some data was updated, and you can run your handler.

Below is my stored procedure for getting the last updated date.

This is a great way to implement caching, so you only need to re-pull data when it changes.

Good luck!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTableLastUpdatedDate]
@TableName nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT max(last_user_update) as LastUpdatedDate
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE
    database_id = DB_ID( 'MyDatabaseName') and 
    OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(@TableName)

END
```